# AWS deleted sub-domain then re-added, now inaccessible

Tags: amazon-web-services, subdomain, amazon-route53

I have a primary domain which points to an EC2 instance which works fine. I setup a sub-domain via [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/CreatingNewSubdomain.html)  article. I pointed this sub-domain to the same ec2 instance which then served different resources via Apache2.

As I am still new to AWS, I wanted to try something out, the something being not using a second hosting zone for the sub domain. So I deleted the sub domains hosted zone and removed the related name records from the primary domains record set.

I did my little experiment, which didn't work. I once again removed all of the name records related to the sub domain from the primary domains hosted zone. I then followed the same article to re-setup the sub-domain. I added the new name service records to the primary domains hosted zone.

Now here's the problem. When I test the sub-domains records, they are all fine. When I test the primary domains name server records for the sub-domain, it responds with NOERROR but it also does not point to the EC2 instance. If I try to navigate to the sub-domain via the browser, a "server DNS address could not be found" is returned. Yet, when I run a tool like [DNS Lookup](http://mxtoolbox.com/DNSLookup.aspx), the correct name servers are resolved.

What am I missing here?

Additional information:
The name servers in the sub domain look like this:

```
name: blog.quotr.ca
ns-1028.awsdns-00.org.
ns-253.awsdns-31.com.
ns-1778.awsdns-30.co.uk.
ns-576.awsdns-08.net.
```

The primary domains hosted zone entry for the sub-domain looks like this:

```
name: blog.quotr.ca
ns-1028.awsdns-00.org.
ns-253.awsdns-31.com.
ns-1778.awsdns-30.co.uk.
ns-576.awsdns-08.net.
```

Please note, navigation to the primary domain quotr.ca is still accessible (albeit locked down to my ip currently).

Thank you

Comment: Your [WHOIS entry](https://www.networksolutions.com/whois/results-res.jsp?domain=quotr.ca) is showing a different set of Name Servers. You'll need to figure out which set is correct and make sure that's appearing against your domain.

Comment: Those are the name servers for the primary domain, not the sub domain.

Comment: The subdomain uses the same name server as the primary domain. The `NS` records are against the domain in Route 53. Then just create the sub-domains within the same Hosted Zone.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, that fixed it. I'm not sure why it worked before but that doesn't matter at this point. If you want to make your comment an answer; I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subdomain uses the same name server as the primary domain. The `NS` records are against the domain in Route 53.

Then just create the sub-domains within the same Hosted Zone.